# google-bigquery update table using another table

Tags: google-bigquery

Hi I have two tables in BigQuery:

TableA : consumerID,consumerSegment

TableB : consumerID

All I want to do is to update TableA.consumerSegment with "found" where TableA.consumerID=TableB.consumerID

I am using this statement but in return, I am getting an error:

```
UPDATE `MyTableLongNameA` AS TableA

SET TableA.consumerSegment = "Found"

FROM `MyTableLongNameB` AS TableB

WHERE TableA.consumerID = TableB.ConsumerID
```

The error is:

> Scalar subquery produced more than one element

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This indicates that there is more than one match in `TableB` for a key from `TableA`. From [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#update_statement):

> If a row in the table to be updated joins with exactly one row from the FROM clause, then the row is updated.
>
> If a row in the table to be updated joins with more than one row from FROM clause, then the query generates a runtime error.

Try this instead:

```
UPDATE `MyTableLongNameA` AS TableA
SET TableA.consumerSegment = "Found"
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM `MyTableLongNameB` AS TableB
  WHERE TableA.consumerID = TableB.ConsumerID
)
```

Comment: Thanks for help Elliott.